# CSS: min-height: min-content fails to override height

Tags: css, responsive-design

I recreated an issue I've been facing with the toy example here

https://jsfiddle.net/958z6ckh/3/

```css
.test{
  height: 5px;
  min-height: min-content;
  background: red;
  border: solid;
}
```

````html
<div class="test">
  <div>
    testljalfdkajsfldjdsalfjdsalfxsdal
    asfsadfasdfslafjlskdjfklsdjfklslsf
    askdlfjdslkajflkdsajflktestljalfdk
    ajsfldjdsalfjdsalfxsdal
    asfsadfasdfslafjlskdjfklsdjfklslsf
    askdlfjdslkajflkdsajflk
  </div>
</div>
```
````

I've found similar questions with workarounds but no answers that get to the crux of why `min-height: min-content;` fails to override the height property. Thanks

Edit:
To clarify, this is a contrived example. The original desired result was to create a smooth-scroll webpage with sections that each have height equal to the view height minus the navbar unless it is insufficient to prevent overflow or require a scroll for the content. The same result could be achieved with just `min-height: calc(100vh - 80px);`. The bug simply led me to investigate and come up empty handed as to why the code in the example above does not produce the same result and appears to ignore the `min-height`.

Comment: I am not understanding why height: auto; min-height: 5px (or whatever) doesn't achieve the result you want.

Comment: `height: fit-content;`  will ensure all the content within the element is *fit* into the element in turn never ***shrinking*** smaller than it's content.

Comment: I do not see `height: calc(100vh - 80px);` in your example, where is this rule? Perhaps you can adjust your snippit to show how you are incorporating this rule in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#sizing-values):

> `min-content`
>
> Use the min-content size in the relevant axis; for a box’s block size, unless otherwise specified, this is equivalent to **its automatic size**.

Then for "automatic size":

> For `min-width`/`min-height`, specifies an automatic minimum size. Unless otherwise defined by the relevant layout module, however, **it resolves to a used value of 0.**

So `min-height: min-content` will resolve to `min-height: 0`. In other words, it has no effect.